# How to prove this number is not rational?

Tags: calculus

Consider $$x\:=\:\sum _{k=0}^t\frac{1}{k!}+\frac{\alpha }{t\cdot t!}$$
with $t\in \mathbb{N},\:\alpha \in \left(0,1\right)$. How can I prove that  $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ ?

So far I assume in negative that $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, so it must exist some $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ that follow that $$x\:=\:\frac{z}{t\:}\:=\:\sum _{k=0}^t\:\frac{1}{k!}\:+\:\frac{\alpha }{t\cdot t!}$$ but I stuck here. What to do?

Comment: What is the smallest number that you need to multiply the first sum with to get an integer?

Comment: What do you know about $\alpha$? There *certainly* exist $\alpha\in(0,1)$that make $x$ rational. (And why does your title talk about integers, when the question is about rationals?)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo sorry i don't understand you..

Comment: Surely $x$ is rational if (and only if?) $\alpha$ is rational. All the operations preserve rationality.

Comment: @nec if the first sum is multiplied by $t!$, it will be an integer. The part $\frac{\alpha}{t\cdot t!}$ will be rational if $\alpha$ is rational. I guess, you're going to have a hard time proving that the entire expression isn't a rational number for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is rational then $x$ is rational, and if $\alpha$ is irrational then $x$ is irrational. You can't proceed any further without knowing more about $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is now, it all depends whether $\alpha$ is rational or not. $\sum_{k=0}^t 1/k!$ since it is a finite sum of rational numbers (because the rational numbers are a field, or even a ring would be enough). Since $t$ is an integer $\alpha / (t! \cdot t)$ is rational if and only if $\alpha$ is rational.